# How does one pause a Vimeo video without using an iframe

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, oembed

Viemo has an amazing API, but there doesn't seem to be a way to manually pause a video using JavaScript or oEmbeded. I've done a lot of research on this topic and there is a lot of stuff about playing and pausing vimeo videos in iframe, and somethings about video, but there isn't anything about pausing it using a oEmbed div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the below code.

```
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);
<button onclick="return pause()">Pause </button>
function pause(){
    player.pause();
}
```

Comment: I'm so sorry that I just now got this, this worked well, thank you!